# ERROR mapping.DefaultUrlMappingEvaluator$UrlMappingBuilder - URL mapping argument [exception] with value [(*)] must be a valid class

Tags: grails, error-handling, urlmappings.groovy

I am having this error in my grails log:

Error |
ERROR mapping.DefaultUrlMappingEvaluator$UrlMappingBuilder  - URL mapping argument [exception] with value [(*)] must be a valid class

It is not stopping the application, but I would like to know why is happening. I have detected that is because the URLMapping.groovy:

```
    "500"(controller:"securator", action:"error500", exception:InternalServerErrorException)
    "401"(controller:"securator", action:"error401", exception:IllegalAccessException)
    "403"(controller:"securator", action:"error403", exception:AccessDeniedException)
```

If I remove the last exception, the error disappear:

> , exception:AccessDeniedException

Anyone has any ideas?, how can I use a valid class (I thought that AccessDeniedException was a valid class)?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you show place in code where it's thrown? (probably controller or service). 

Are you using any authorization plugins?

Comment: I am using Spring Security. The errors thrown when I run de app, at the very begining (just after configuring Spring Security).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally resolved, I change the exception to ForbiddenException. It looks good and no error thrown.

Answer (score 2):

I got the same error (just with another exception) today, the simple solution is to import the class.

My code in UrlMappings.groovy that caused the error:

```
"500"(controller: "error", action: "grailsTagException", exception: GrailsTagException)
```

I got the same ERROR message as GSAN, added import of the class:

```
import org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.taglib.exceptions.GrailsTagException;
```

Now my project compiles without errors. Hope that helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to change `AccessDeniedException` to abstract class [AuthenticationException](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/core/AuthenticationException.html).